# Popup modal confirmation dialog during form Validation

Tags: forms, javascript

I have a standard From API form.  When the user clicks the submit button I'd like to popup a modal dialog with some details relate to the submitted field with a proceed ( to submission ) and cancel ( return to from ) button.

However I'm not sure where to start.  Should I add an #ajax callback on the submit button perhaps ?  Any advice appreciated.

Pseudo-code here :

```
function mymodule_search_form() {
  $form['code'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Search for documents',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#description' => 'Enter a code',
'#access' => TRUE,
  );    
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Search'),
'#access' => TRUE,
  );
  return $form;
 }

function mymodule_search_form_validate($form, $form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['code'] !== 'acceptable code') {
    form_set_error('code', 'Invalid code');
  }
  // deconstruct $form_state['values']['code']

  // popup dialog "Your code indicates BLAH BLAH". Click Proceed to continue
  // or Cancel to try again"
}

function mymodule_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'assets';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it Form API form? Or one created with Webform? Quickforms? Or is it entity edit form? There are many ways to forms in Drupal :)

Comment: Sorry.  Just standard Form API.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Just edit your question stating it is indeed a form api form and providing a code you are using to create it - with notes on what things you need confirmed. Your edit will trigger reopen vote :)

Comment: Any answer for this Question ???